# Are unimposed or uncompelled vows (or any related synonyms) annulled by "Kol Nidrei"?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, yom-kippur, nedarim-shevuot, kol-nidre

Are the following vows (or any related synonyms) annulled by "Kol Nidrei":

Any vows or promises or oath (or any related synonyms) that I said to God? For example, I say, God, I promise to give 20% of my income to you?

Any vows or promises or oath (or any related synonyms) that I said to my friend or relative, who did not impose or compel me to make such a vow? For example, I say, If you shut up, then I will give you a gift.

Comment: ninamag, the answer is Kol Nidrei does absolutely nothing.

Comment: There are those who say that those forced to take an oath like the covers in Spain felt guilty for *violating* the invalid oath.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Hatarat Nedarim](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=9/15/2011) a person should do this as an individual in front of a *bais din* of three people.

[Hatarat Nedarim – Annulling Vows Before Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=375)

> It is customary to conduct “Hatarat Nedarim” – the formal annulment of
>   vows – before Rosh Hashanah and before Yom Kippur. This declaration is
>   made in the presence of three people that serve as a Bet Din
>   (Rabbinical court). It absolves a person from vows he made and from
>   customs which he accepted upon himself. Preferably, a person should
>   perform Hatarat Nedarim in the presence of ten men, as this kind of
>   Bet Din has more authority than a three-member Bet Din.
>
> As part of the Hatarat Nedarim declaration, a person says that
>   although Halacha requires a person to specify the particular vows
>   which he wishes to annul, he is unable to do so because they are too
>   numerous. The work Derech Ha’haim cites from the Shiboleh Ha’leket
>   (Rav Sidkiya Ben Abraham, Italy, 1230-1300) that this special
>   provision applies only to vows of which a person is unaware. One can
>   earn annulment for these vows by informing the Bet Din that he cannot
>   recall his vows. If, however, a person is aware of a certain vow or
>   custom from which he wishes to absolve himself, then he must specify
>   it when he makes the Hatarat Nedarim declaration.

This is better as it shows that a person has been careful about oaths and would not rely on the general statement.

[Kol Nidre](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9443-kol-nidre/)

> The readiness with which vows were made and the facility with which
>   they were annulled by the scribes gave the Karaites an opportunity to
>   attack the Rabbinites, and forced the Geonim to minimize the power of
>   dispensation. Yehudai Gaon of Sura (760), author of the "Halakot
>   Pesuḳot," went so far as to forbid any study whatsoever of Nedarim,
>   the Talmudic treatise on oaths (Alfasi on Nedarim, end; L. Löw, l.c.
>   p. 363). Thus the "Kol Nidre" was discredited in both of the
>   Babylonian academies and was not accepted by them (S. K. Stern, in
>   "Ḳebuẓat Ḥakamim," ed. Warnheim, 1861), as is affirmed by the geonim
>   Naṭronai (853-856) and Hai Bar Naḥshon (889-896; Müller, "Mafteaḥ," p.
>   103; Cassel, "Teshubot Geonim Ḳadmonim," p. 9; Zunz, "Ritus," p. 189;
>   Ṭur Oraḥ Ḥayyim, § 619; "Kol Bo," § 68). Amram Gaon in his "Siddur"
>   (l.c.) calls the custom of reciting the "Kol Nidre" a foolish one
>   ("minhag sheṭut"). According to Naṭronai, however, it was customary to
>   recite the formula in various lands of the Jewish dispersion, and it
>   is clear likewise from Amram's "Siddur" (ii. 37a) that the usage was
>   wide-spread as early as his time in Spain. But the geonic practise of
>   not reciting the "Kol Nidre" was long prevalent; it has never been
>   adopted in the Catalonian or in the Algerian ritual (Zunz, l.c. p.
>   106); and there were always many congregations in lands where the
>   Provençal and Spanish ritual was used which did not recite it ("Orḥot
>   Ḥayyim," p. 105d; comp. also RaN to Ned. 23b, where it is said: "There
>   are some congregations which usually recite the 'Kol Nidre' on the Day
>   of Atonement")

[Rabbeinu Tam](http://etzion.org.il/en/kol-nidrei-and-repentance-yom-kippur) states that it only effects the future and not the past.

> Rabbenu Tam (1100–1171), however, disagrees, and raises many
>   objections to the traditional understanding of Kol Nidrei (Rosh, Yoma
>   8:28). He insists that Kol Nidrei does not affect the past by
>   annulling previous vows, but rather stipulates that any vow that one
>   will take in the future should not be binding. Indeed, the Talmud
>   (Nedarim 23b) teaches:
>
> And he who desires that none of his vows made during the year shall be
>   valid, let him stand at the beginning of the year and declare, "Every
>   vow which I may make in the future shall be null."  [His vows are then
>   invalid,] provided that he remembers this at the time of the vow. But
>   if he remembers, has he not cancelled the declaration and confirmed
>   the vow? ... Raba said: … Here the circumstances are, for example,
>   that one stipulated at the beginning of the year, but does not know in
>   reference to what. Now he vows. Hence, if he remembers [the
>   stipulation] and he declares: "I vow in accordance with my original
>   intention," his vow has no reality. But if he does not declare thus,
>   he has cancelled his stipulation and confirmed his vow.